# Add file to sub-folder to ZIP archive?

Tags: php, archive, php-ziparchive

I want to add subfolder with file to archive.

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```

I can't use it, because I don't need all files of my folder.
I have array with some information about files:

```
$paths = [
[
    'name' => 'file',
    'ext'  => 'txt',
    'path' => '/folder/'
],
[
    'name' => 'subFolder',
    'ext'  => 'folder',
    'path' => '/folder/'
],
[
    'name' => 'fileInSubFolder',
    'ext'  => 'txt',
    'path' => '/folder/subFolder/'
]
];
```

In cycle I do it:

```
if( $folder[$i]['ext'] == 'folder' )
    $zip->addEmptyDir($fileName);
else 
    $zip->addFromString( $fileName.$fileExt, file_get_contents($fileFullPath.$fileExt));
```

If "folder", then I create empty folder in archive, else add file to archive.
But if file locate in subfolder so file will add to root of archive.
And, how can I add file to new empty subfolder?
Or how can I change current directory for add file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not "change directory" with [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) you always pass the absolute file path when adding a file.

Now, I'm not sure why you have a `$paths` array but then you loop through `$folders` since I cannot see all of your code, but if you were looping through your `$paths` array  you would want to append the absolute path you have stored to the front of the file name.

```
$paths = [
[
    'name' => 'file',
    'ext'  => 'txt',
    'path' => '/folder/'
],
[
    'name' => 'subFolder',
    'ext'  => 'folder',
    'path' => '/folder/'
],
[
    'name' => 'fileInSubFolder',
    'ext'  => 'txt',
    'path' => '/folder/subFolder/'
]
];


if( $paths[$i]['ext'] == 'folder' ) {
    $zip->addEmptyDir($fileName);
} else {
    // This would create "/folder/subFolder/fileInSubFolder.txt"
    $fullFileName= $paths[$i]['path'] . $paths[$i]['name'] . "." . $paths[$i]['ext'];
    $zip->addFromString( $fullFileName, /* File Data Here */);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just confused. I thought that first parameter in "addFromString" it's just file name, but there need put relative path, start from folder that you want to archive.

Thank you very much!